# Enhanced Enums cause Flutter app to hang when used in widget

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I am trying to upgrade my code to use the new enhanced enum feature of dart 2.17 and flutter 3.0.5.

Here is my enum:

```
enum Permission {
  first(1, "first"),
  second(2, "second");

  const Permission(this.id, this.name);

  final int id;
  final String name;
}
```

Usage, called in build() of a stateful widget:

```
String name = Permission.first.name;
```

When I run my program everything compiles and I get no error messages, but the program hangs on a white screen and constantly reloads, never making it to the home screen. If I comment out the line where I access the name of the permission, everything loads and runs properly. Not sure why accessing the enum property causes the program to break. Any reason this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `name` as a filed on enum. It is already having a [`.name` extension](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/EnumName.html) on enum.

```dart
enum Permission {
  first(1, "first"),
  second(2, "second");

  const Permission(this.id, this.value);

  final int id;
  final String value; //change it to something else
}
```

Now `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Not sure why the Flutter docs only mention "values" as a reserved member name.

Comment: values will provide  items of the enum

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is that on the dart.dev documentation there is a part that reads "A member named values cannot be declared in an enum, as it would conflict with the automatically generated static values getter." But for some reason, a similar warning about using the name field is not documented.

Comment: @jawsofdoom As explained, the `name` field is added as an *extension* method, so name collisions are handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to this bug in Flutter that should be fixed in the next versions: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103656